# VB.NET property declaration

Tags: .net, vb.net, properties, backing-field

I see we can define properties in two way in VB.NET.

As below

```
 Private newPropertyValue As String
    Public Property ID() As String
        Get
            Return newPropertyValue
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            newPropertyValue = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

Or as below in one line

```
Public Property ID As String
```

Is there any difference or later is an improved way to define properties.

Comment: You start with the bottom one.  And then some day you'll switch to the top one because you need to put more code in the accessors, usually the Set()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want basic accessors use the shorthand, it sets everything up for you and is easier to read in my opinion.

However you will need to use the standard syntax if you want to:

- Include any extra processing such as validation.
- Have different accessibility for each accessor (private get, public set)
- Use write or read only properties

Plenty of extra info here as well: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293589.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The second format is called an [Auto-Implemented property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293589.aspx). Is is just shorthand for the first option. If you don't need any logic or additional code when getting or setting a property you can use this.

You can access the backing field of an auto implemented property using the name:

```
_[PropertName]
```

But I would advise against this.

When you need some code or logic in your property you have to use the first option.

Currently (VS2013) if you want a read-only or write-only property then you have to use the longhand version. In VS2015 you can use [auto implemented properties for these as well](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/blogs/tool-tracker/2015/05/vb-14-readonly-auto-implemented-properties.aspx).